# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (UserRepository, UserFactory, ?)

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

Nest.js is writing a test code using jest.
Dependency Injection does not work.
It does not work even when all providers included in the module are applied.

```
const mockAuthService = {
  hashPassword: jest.fn(),
};

const mockUserFactory = {
  createUser: jest.fn(),
};

const MockUserRepository = {
  create: jest.fn(),
  save: jest.fn(),
  find: jest.fn(),
  findOne: jest.fn(),
};

describe('UserService', () => {
  let userService: UserService;
  let mockUserRepository: Repository<User>;
  let authService: AuthService;
  let userFactory: UserFactory;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        UserService,
        { provide: getRepositoryToken(User), useValue: MockUserRepository },
        { provide: UserFactory, useValue: mockUserFactory },
        { provide: AuthService, useValue: mockAuthService },
      ],
    }).compile();

    userService = module.get<UserService>(UserService);
    mockUserRepository = module.get<Repository<User>>(getRepositoryToken(User));
    authService = module.get<AuthService>(AuthService);
    userFactory = module.get<UserFactory>(UserFactory);
  });

  it('Success', async () => {
    // given
    const user = new SignUpRequestDto();
    user.email = 'test@example.com';
    user.password = 'testpassword';
    mockUserFactory.createUser.mockReturnValue(new User(user.email, user.password));
    MockUserRepository.findOne.mockRejectedValue([]);
    mockAuthService.hashPassword.mockResolvedValue('hashPassword');
    MockUserRepository.save.mockReturnValue(new User(user.email, user.password));

    // When
    const result = await userService.create(user);

    // Then
    expect(result).toHaveProperty('email', user.email);
  });
```

You cannot create all providers.
What's the problem?
How do we solve this problem?

The configuration of the User Service is as follows.

```
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User) private userRepository: Repository<User>,
    private userFactory: UserFactory,
    private authService: AuthService,
  ) {}
```

Comment: the target provider is `UserService`. Thus, you must show us how its dependencies. Show us `UserService#constructor`

Comment: I posted it in my post.
UserService#constructor

Comment: Can you provide the full error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

It was a circular dependency issue.
Resolved with forwardRef.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about how you used forwardRef to solve the problem?